# captcha code is showing undefined in ie7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My captcha code is working fine in all browsers, but it is showing error in ie7.

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KMupW/4/

Here is my code :

```
function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}
 var code= randomString(5,'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

 document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
 document.getElementById("txtCaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;
```

Comment: Make sure that `Math.random()` is giving proper index. Have a alert and see as you will have only 5 alerts.

Comment: its working fine in all other browser so math.random is giving proper index...

Comment: I am telling specifically about **IE7**. When you execute in **IE7** have a alert and see.

Comment: Why are we generating captcha codes in JavaScript? What purpose does this serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result += chars[index];
```

Problem is here, internet explorer doesn't support string manipulation like arrays, you should write this instead:

```
result += chars.charAt(index);
```

So the line should finally be:

```
result += chars.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1)));
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/XDxR7/2/

Comment: you want me to add it this way ??
result += chars.charAt([Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))]);

Comment: `result += chars.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1)));`

Comment: What error message exactly do you have? Probably you are running the javascript code instantly without waiting the page to load, and thus getElementById fails because the corresponding element is not loaded yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26467/discussion-between-sachin-rawal-and-aram90)

Comment: thnx its working..I was uploading wrong file.My BAD..thanku so much